# Typescript Method TS2322 error

Tags: typescript

I am able to create an Typescript class object, however every time I create any method on the class it breaks.

```
export class VacationServerResults {

 vacationOffers: Array<VacationHotelTicketDateOffersModel>;


constructor() {
    this.vacationOffers = new Array<VacationHotelTicketDateOffersModel>();

}

public greet() {
    return "hello";
}   

}
```

Everytime I add the greet method, I get the following error.

> file:
>   'file:
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'Type '{ "vacationOffers": {
>   "vacationOffer": { "offerType": string; "hotelRoomBasePrice": number;
>   "hote...' is not assignable to type 'VacationServerResults'.
>   Property 'greet' is missing in type '{ "vacationOffers": {
>   "vacationOffer": { "offerType": string; "hotelRoomBasePrice": number;
>   "hote...'.' at: '36,5' source: 'ts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have another place in your code where you assign an object literal to an object of type `VacationServerResults`. Typescript uses structural compatibility to determine type compatibility, so the following code is valid:

```
class Dog {
  name: string;
}

var d: Dog = {name : "My dog"};
```

Once you add a method the object literal will no longer satisfy the structure of the class and we get your error. You could do one of the following:

Assign the method in the object literal (a rather hack-ish solution)

```
class Dog {
  name: string;
  bark(): void{}
}

var d: Dog = {name : "My dog", bark: Dog.prototype.bark };
```

Create a constructor for your class that takes the object literal and new-up your objects instead of using object literals:

```
class Dog {
  constructor(props: { name: string }){
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }
  name: string;
  bark(): void{}
}

var d = new Dog({name : "My dog" });
```

Comment: Titan, I think you answer is correct, but I do have follow up question.

Comment: @user2502794 sure, what question ?

Comment: Titan, I think you answer is correct, but I do have follow up question because I am trying to manipulate a complex object then generate a new object.  How do you deal with nested objects? class DogCollection {

    dogs: Array<String>;

    constructor(props:{dogs:Array<string>}) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
//test
let vetDogs = new DogCollection({ "dogs": [{ "happy", "grumpy"}]})

Comment: If the dogs array is actually of `string` you can just assign it like you do in the sample, you need to created like this though `new DogCollection({ "dogs": [ "happy", "grumpy"]})`

Comment: @user2502794 If the dogs array is of dogs you would need to map them to the dog type : `dogs: Array<Dog>; 
   constructor(props:{dogs:Array<{ name: string }>}) {
      Object.assign(this, props); 
      this.dogs = props.dogs.map(p => new Dog(p));
    }`